# Best Laptob for blender

Tags: animation

I would like to buy a better laptop than mine for well learning 3d modelling, sculpting and animation..I have Asus Rog Scar Intel core i7-7700HQ, Nivida Geforce GTX... But it's really slow and can't deal will with animation & with sculpture mode "dyntopo" for example.
Please can you orient me to best laptops that are very performant for blender 3d & animation, with best ventilation system and the most silent fans since I'm sensible to noise. I can go to a budget for 3000/3500 euro but for this price i have to be sure it's really a high game with great performances and not to be surprised of a ventilation system that would blow my ears and burn my hands (:

I noticed that the most performant processors as mentioned on "blender open data" is AMD EPCY or Ryzen is it the same for laptops? or I can go for Intel core i9 3070/80 or 4070/80?
Another question for windows, does windows 11 work well for blender? is it better in family version or professional?

Thank you very much,

Comment: In addition to that amazing answer by Duarte, you should also check the official [System Requirements for Blender](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/)  page as well as [rendering benchmarks](https://opendata.blender.org/). Also if you are unsure about what you need, it might not be a bad idea not to rush. Use Blender with what you have for a while to see what you need.

Comment: Thank u. I have already researched for the requirements needed to run blender in a performant way for 3d, sculpt&animation (CPU, GPU, MotherCard..) I saw lot of videos, comparisons & they r too commercial. My question concerned Laptobs,because even with high CPU, GPU, etc, they could not run well & match to their attended performances. That's because they would overheat, stop to respond, or become too loud that we cant work with. So if there are experienced blender-users that use laptobs & can give advice for a high performant laptob that doesn't overheat with a crazy noisy ventilation system.

Comment: My other question is about windows, what is better to run blender 4 and up, windows 10 or 11  & what version (familly, professional). There are too many opposite opinions about this on the net. Thank u very much

Comment: It's opinion. I would NEVER consider working on a laptop with those small screens and uncomfortable keyboards, I use 32" 4K monitor in the office, 43" 4K TV at home, the office one seems small to me, but its colors are more accurate. Laptops are uncomfortable to work with and a waste of money in my eyes. If I had spare money, I would get RTX4090, I only have RTX3060, it has 12GB, but I want more, it's computing power is fine with me, I have 32GB of RAM, that's fine, I don't care about CPU(Ryzen5600X sort of works) I got an expensive SSD with 1700M/s read/write speeds, it helps me a lot.

Comment: I have another big screen beside my laptob and my keyboard is comfortable. Thanks a lot for trying but always you don't answer my questions.

Comment: Having to move my head and eyes to look around the big screen is a plus for me, because I work at least 8 hours a day and I don't like sitting still for 8 hours. I wouldn't trade it for the best laptop out there. I am thinking about better CPU, for cloth simulations I sometimes need, but I don't really need it now, because I really don't use it that much :D. I sometimes run out of VRAM, in cases I am lazy to optimize my scenes, I should, but that's extra time, so more VRAM would be great.

Comment: Having 2 screens is never as comfortable as one bigger one for me. I would have to switch my wacom tablet between them.

Comment: So you see, I would tend to advice to not get a laptop, get a bigger screen instead, save on RAM and CPU and get more expensive GPU and SSD. That would be my advice. It isn't. I don't advise that. Because that is for me, not for you. This is why nobody can really answer your question well.

Comment: OS is the same deal. Only you can decide. Blender works fine on all: Windows 10 and 11, home and professional versions. No difference as far as I can tell. It may even run smoother on Linux and it used to render faster on Linux. Is it worth it? I don't know. Only you can decide. Blender will work fine, other factors in your circumstances are more important regarding the OS.

Comment: If you're unsure, you can download Windows and test it for 30 days for free without activation. You also can install it on a [virtual machine](https://www.virtualbox.org/) (not sure if Blender runs on it). Depending on the key, you can upgrade Windows 10 to 11 for free. Or try Linux, Blender runs well on it & Win10 -- AMD Epyc and Threadripper are server CPUs, not for laptops. You can learn Blender on a $2000 laptop with an integrated GPU. But rendering takes a while. There will be always noise & heat when rendering, no matter which hardware. Gaming laptops often have better ventilation.